# Photo Editing Monitor suggestion? 30-32 inch 4k <=$1200

Tags: monitors

I'm looking for a 32 inch 4k monitor for general use as well as photo editing.  I'm just an amatuer photographer so I'm not super picky but I want something that will last a while. My budget is $1200.00.

I've looked at the Dell u3219q, Benq pd3200u. I don't like that the Dell is not flicker free and I'm not sure if I should be concerned about the color range of the Benq and lack of HDR.  I also bought two Asus pa329q's but they both had dead pixels so I sent them back and am looking elsewhere.

Any recommendations?

**Edit**
Another possible option is LG's 32UL950-W

Comment: What's your issue with the color range of the BenQ? Seems to have better Color coverage than the Dell. (And comparing to the added LG would rather be this BenQ https://amzn.to/2SQfnMu)

Answer (score 0):

Actually I'm thinking to buy the Samsung UR59C (4K, 32", 60Hz). I imagine that it's what you're looking for, and the price is just amazing.

You can find more about it [here](https://www.samsung.com/us/computing/monitors/curved/32-ur59c-curved-4k-uhd-monitor-lu32r590cwnxza/).

[image: samsung]